# Active Record - Doing a join on a query result

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to do something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
@events = Event.where(date:'10/10/2014')
@venues = Venue.joins(@events)
```

I know the proper syntax is `Venue.joins(:events)` but this joins all events with a venue_id, which is every single one. I want to get all the venues that are tied to a specific subset of events.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, I'm assuming that each `Event` has a `Venue`. To find all the venues of a set of events, use:

```
@events = Event.where(date: '10/10/2014')
@venues = Venue.where('id IN(?)', @events.map(&:venue_id))
```

The `map` method transforms the collection of events into an array of their `venue_id`s.
If you want to avoid the performance hit from extracting the venue IDs outside the database, this code may be  more helpful:

```
@venues = Venue.where('id IN(SELECT events.venue_id FROM events WHERE date = ?)', '10/10/2014')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complement to Arvoreniad's answer I just found. The other one works, but seems a little hacky compared to this pure active record solution:

```
Venue.joins(:events).where(events: {id: @events})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating an array of events just to get the venues is pretty inefficient. I would do it like so:

```
@venues = Venue.joins(:events).where(events: {date: '10/10/2014'})
```

Comment: You're correct. But in my specific use case I was using `@events` for a few different purposes, so since it's already instantiated, it makes sense to use it for the join. I also simplified the question for the sake of getting a clear answer. `@events` is being subjected to multiple variabled scopes and is not simply being queried by a specific date.

Comment: I see. If you know you will need the venues at the time you load the events you can also do something like `Event.includes(:venue).where("...")` to trigger eager loading of the related venues.